# Why sending an array as an actual parameter to function which expects a pointer to an array needs dereferencing 2 times to access the array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, dereference

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int (*x)[3]) {
    return **x*2; // Why we need to dereference two times here?
}
int main(void) {
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("%d", fun(a)); // 2
}
```

So what I know is that the array name acts as an address of the array only, and in the function the x is also expecting an address of the array so why we need to dereference the x two times and not one?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Why do you think that's correct, given all the warnings that the compiler outputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters in this call

```
printf("%d", fun(a));
```

the expression `a` (the array designator) is implicitly converted to pointer to the element type that is has the type `int *`.

At the same time the function parameter has the type `int ( * )[3]`.

There is no implicit conversion from the type `int *` to the type `int ( * )[3]`. So the compiler shall issue an error.

The function call must look like

```
printf("%d", fun( &a ));
```

Within the function dereferencing the pointer `x` you will get an object of the type `int[3]` that is lvalue of the original array. Again used in expressions (with rare exceptions) the array designator is converted to the pointer of the type `int *` that points to its first element.

So to access this first element of the array you need to dereference the expression one more

```
**x*2
```

You have the following chain of conversions of expressions

```
&a -> int ( *x )[3]

*x -> int[3]

int[3] -> int *

*( int * ) -> int
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially passing an array of int pointers as a parameter to `fun`.

Had you only passed `int x[3]` to the function, you would have only had to dereference it once.